# 3 out of 4 picklistvalues should make a field mandatory // validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

Hello dear developers,

I have a really simple task (on paper) but just can´t get my head around (I´m no developer and don´t have the mindset to think in even if-then...)

I have a dedicated opportunity record with some dedicated fields on it. The task is this: 3 out of 4 picklist values should make a lookup-field mandatory.

I tried this and didn´t even get over the syntax check:

```
AND (
$User.Bypass_Validation__c = FALSE,

AND(
RecordTypeId<>"0129W0000004JhH",
And(
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Increase Budget"),
ISPICKVAL(Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Renew Campaign"),
ISPICKVAL(Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Cancel Campaign"),
AND(
ISBLANK(Original_Opportunity__c),
)
)
)))
```

Then I dumbed down and tried this:

```
AND(
    OR(
        Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Increase Budget",
        Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Renew Campaign"
    ),
   ISBLANK(Original_Opportunity__c)
)
```

Then I read that with picklist values you should use CASE() and that is where I raise a white flag. This is my first question here so please be gentle if I miss some points :)

Could any good samaritan out there help me out on this?

Kind regards
Alex

Comment: Welcome to SSE! Do you mean if any of the three picklist values are selected then the lookup field is to be made mandatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such condition to use `CASE()` function for picklist values. It depends on the scenario .

Here in your scenario we need to check that picklist should contain any of the three values And if lookup field is blank it should throw Error.

The one which you tried at last is working scenario just you need to add other picklist value .

```
AND( 
OR(
ISPICKVAL( tst1__c ,"Increase Budget"),
ISPICKVAL(tst1__c,"Renew Campaign"),
ISPICKVAL(tst1__c,"Cancel Campaign")), 
ISBLANK( Field1__c ))
```

The main issue in your First attempt is the syntax of AND() . You have added extra AND() conditions there.

```
AND (
$User.Bypass_Validation__c = FALSE,
RecordTypeId<>"0129W0000004JhH",
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Increase Budget"),
ISPICKVAL(Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Renew Campaign"),
ISPICKVAL(Campaign_Use_Case__c,"Cancel Campaign")
),
ISBLANK(Original_Opportunity__c)
)
```

Comment: Thank you SaiPraveen. But when I copie your code into SF I get a error msg:
Error: Syntax error. Found ')' Line 1 Column 1
But everything is opend and closed right?

Comment: @AlexM., Have you copied the second part of my answer or first part?

Comment: There was an extra comma in the second part of my answer . Removed it. Can you check now

Comment: Ahh, upps. I only copied the second part. Just a second :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Works like a charm.